# Undefined variable error in PHP. How can I fix it?

Tags: php, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

I got an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: pollid

What's wrong here?

```
<?php
    $pollid = $_GET['pollid'];
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','test','apklausa1');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE pollid='$pollid'";
    $q = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
        $id = $row[0];
        $title = $row[1];
        $pollid = $row[2];
        $ipaddress = $row[3];
        echo "<h1>$title</h1>";
?>

        <table>
            <form action="" method="POST">

<?php
            $questions = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE pollid='$pollid'";
            $q2 = mysqli_query($connect, $questions);
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q2)) {
            $question = $r[1];
            $votes = $r[2];
            $newvotes = $votes + 1;
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $newipaddress = $ipaddress."$ip,";

            if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
                $polloption = $_POST['polloption'];
                if ($polloption == "") {
                    die("You didn't select an option.");
                } else {

                        $ipaddresse = explode(",", $ipaddress);
                        if (in_array($ip, $ipaddresse)) {
                            die("You've already voted");
                        } else {
                    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE questions SET votes='$newvotes' WHERE pollid='$pollid' AND question='$polloption'");
                    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE polls SET ipaddress='$newipaddress' WHERE pollid='$pollid'");
                    die("You voted Successfully");
                    }
                }
            }

            echo
              '<tr><td>' . $question .
              '</td><td><input type="radio" name="polloption" value="' .
              $question .
              '" /> ' . $votes .
              ' votes</td></tr>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$_GET['pollid']` is not defined or have no value

Comment: can you specify line number

Answer (score 0):

You need to see where the value of `$_GET['pollid']` is coming from.

Probably the error is coming because the variable `$pollid` is not getting the value. As a result of this it is unset and an error message is getting displayed. Please check the form from where you are making an HTTP GET request. Once the value is received, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['pollid']` is not declared.

There are chances that `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables are not declared in some situation. Using `isset()` helps you to check if the variable is declared or not.

For example,

```
if(isset($_GET['pollid']))
{
   // Your code here
}
```